# Abrir arquivo.js quando MediaQuery é maior que 1024px

Tags: php, java, css, query

No fim do index.php (layout responsivo) tem uma chamada para

```
< script type='text/javascript' src='desk.js'>< /script>
```

Acontece que este JS só vai atuar com MediaQuery maior que 1024px.

**Pergunto:**
É possível fazer uma condição IF no Java ou no próprio CSS que abra este JS ?

O JS é pesado e no mobile não tem função alguma.

Answer (score 1):

Você pode pegar o tamanho da tela pelo window.screen.width ou window.innerWidth e se for menor pode adicionar o arquivo js.
ex:

```
function desktop(){
       if(window.screen.width >= 1024){
           var sc = document.createElement('script')
           sc.src = "desk.js"
           document.querySelector('body').append(sc)
       }
 }
```

[Referência](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Screen/width)

Comment: Obrigado Rodolfo pela orientação. Mas não funcionou.

Coloquei o seu código com < script>, depois com < script type="text/javascript">, no head e no fim < /body>. Parece que o JS não é lido.

(uso este JS há mais de 10 anos, abre quadro de img.peq para img.gde - Obs: funciona normal)

Será que faltou algum comando que não percebi?

Agradeço a colaboração

Comment: se só copiou e colou ele não funciona pois é um função e precisa ser chamada, se colocar desta forma 
(function desktop(){
       if(window.screen.width >= 1024){
           var sc = document.createElement('script')
           sc.src = "desk.js"
           document.querySelector('body').append(sc)
       }
 })()
vai funcionar ao incluir-lá

Comment: Rodolfo. Não funcionou: 
Este funcionou: Mas é enorme (bem maior que o meu arquivo) É ilógico usar um externo para abrir um menor interno.
< script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>if ( $(window).width() >=1024) {      
document.write(unescape("%3Cscript src='desk.js' type='text/javascript'%3E%3C/script%3E"));
}</script>
Obs: Li que usar document.write no js está ultrapassado. E o meu 
desk.js tem. Será que é esta a causa de não aceitar a sua chamada?
 Agradeço a sua atenção

Comment: acabei fazendo o teste aqui, geralmente eu não uso ; no meu código e como esta inline ele precisa usar, o correto é (function desktop(){ if(window.screen.width >= 1024){ var sc = document.createElement('script'); sc.src = "desk.js"; document.querySelector('body').append(sc); } })() usando os ;